# Design two tabs within activity after putting some views in that activity

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am a newbie in Android, how can I do something like that.

I extend TabActivity when to create Tabs like this but without that header.

[image: Activity design]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the view you post here ,you can code the view by yourself:

the header is in the top ,and below the header ,a `TabHost` is needed ,below the `TabHost`,you put a viewpager contains two fragments to display your data,you can control your `viewpager` with method `setCurrentItem` when you click tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator;

public class LauncherActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

        pager.setAdapter(new GuidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    }
}
```

ativity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class GuidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public GuidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        if (pos == 0)
            return new Fragment1();
        else
            return new Fragment2();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

You can add two tabs on main_activity and on click of tab change the fragment in adapter.